# Vb.net how to get the index number of a word table

Tags: vb.net, html-table, ms-word

I select a word html table with a bookmark and want to count de number of rows.

Dim x = oDoc.Bookmarks(bkm).Range.Rows.Count

There are 3 rows in the table.  The result is 1. 
Which I understand. But how to get the result of 3?

Thank you in advance.

Leo van den Berg

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the range method that you are counting rows in a Table.

Dim x = oDoc.Bookmarks(bkm).Range.Tables(1).Range.Rows.Count

Answer (score -1):

All built-in collections are 0 based, so to access a particular index you need to subtract 1 from the natural index (e.g. 1=0, 2=1, 3=2).  So when you're comparing rows.count, the maximum index will then be rows(rows.count-1)

Comment: That is quite irrelevant and misleading. If a row is present, the true count can never be 0!